# UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment error

Tags: python

I tried all the solutions I could find nothing helped

A survey for a school project and expected to add 100 points to the persons score

Do you think you could help

code:

```
#QUESTION

q1 = "TRUE OR FALSE: The lightest atom is hydrogen"
q2 = "TRUE OR FALSE: Osmium is one of the densest atom if not the most"
q3 = "TRUE OR FALSE: chemistry is the branch of science that deals with the identification of the substances of which matter is composed; the investigation of their properties and the ways in which they interact, combine, and change; and the use of these processes to form new substances."
q4 = "TRUE OR FALSE: There are 200 elements discovered in history"
q5 = "TRUE OR FALSE: Dmitri Ivanovich Mendeleev was a Russian chemist and inventor. He is best known for formulating the Periodic Law and creating a version of the periodic table of elements."
#_____________________________________________________________________
 
q6 = "TRUE OR FALSE: The earth is the center of the earth"
q7 = "TRUE OR FALSE: The sun the the center of the earth"
q8 = "TRUE OR FALSE: The sun makes up most of the mass in our solar system"
q9 = "TRUE OR FALSE: Jupiter has the most moon in the solar system"
q10 = "TRUE OR FALSE: Mars's nick name is the red planet"
 #____________________________________________________________________
q11 = "TRUE OR FALSE: Supernova's are the biggest explosions in the universe"
q12 = "TRUE OR FALSE: Gamma rays bursts are the biggest explosions the universe"
q13 = "TRUE OR FALSE: All stars turn into supernovas"
q14 = "TRUE OR FALSE: All stars turn into blacks holes"
q15 = "TRUE OR FALSE: All stars turn into neutron stars"
 #____________________________________________________________________
q16 = "TRUE OR FALSE: Based on the model, Juptier is the biggest planet"
q17 = "TRUE OR FALSE: Based on the model, earth is the samllest planet"
q18 = "TRUE OR FALSE: Based on the model, neptune is the farthest planet to the sun"
q19 = "TRUE OR FALSE: Based on the model, the sun is the biggest object"
q20 = "TRUE OR FALSE: Based on the model the asteroid belt is located between Jupiter and Mars"
 #____________________________________________________________________
 #ANSWER KEY
 
a1 = "True"
a2 = "True"
a3 = "True"
a4 = "False"
a5 = "True"
a6 = "False"
a7 = "True"
a8 = "True"
a9 = "False"
a10 = "True"
a11 = "False"
a12 = "True"
a13 = "False"
a14 = "False"
a15 = "False"
a16 = "True"
a17 = "False"
a18 = "True"
a19 = "True"
a20 = "True"

global player1points
global player2points

player1points = int(0)
player2points = int(0)

startkey = "Start"
rulekey = "Rules"

def software(key):
    if p1!=key and p2!=key:
        print("Both of you got it wrong")

    elif p2==key and p1!=key:
        
        print(f"{p2name} got it right")
        player2points = player2points+int(100)
        
    elif p1==key and p2!=key:
        
        print(f"{p1name} got it right")
       
        player1points = player1points+int(100)
       
    elif p1==key and p2==key:
        
        print("both of you got it right")
        player1points = player1points+int(100)
        player2points = player2points+int(100)
    

start = input(f"Hello to the tester 9000\n\nType start to start\ntype rules to know how to play! ").capitalize().strip()

if start==rulekey:
    rule = input("You need aleast 2 players to play this game\n\neverytime you get the question right you get 100 points\n\n the person with the most points after 20 questions is the winner\ntype start to start")
    
rule = "Start"
    
if start==startkey or rule==startkey:
    p1name = input("what is your name player one: ")
    p2name = input("what is your name player two: ")

print(f"time for you first question")
print(q1)

p1 = input(f"{p1name} turn").capitalize().strip()
p2 = input(f"{p2name} turn").capitalize().strip()

software(a1)

print(player1points)
print(player2points)
```

here the error code it gave me:

```
Hello to the tester 9000

Type start to start
type rules to know how to play! rules
You need aleast 2 players to play this game

everytime you get the question right you get 100 points

 the person with the most points after 20 questions is the winner
type start to startstart
what is your name player one: kunde
what is your name player two: chan
time for you first question
TRUE OR FALSE: The lightest atom is hydrogen
kunde turnfalse
chan turntrue
chan got it right
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 103, in <module>
File "<string>", line 71, in software
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'player2points' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: The `global` statements need to go inside the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Cause of Error**

- The error is your global statements should be inside function software since the global keyword allows us to modify variables outside of the current scope. You need it in the function software

**Improvements**

- Coding is largely about using the right data structures.  Using a variable for each question and answer makes it difficult to loop over the questions and answers.  It's better to use a list in this case.
- No need for global for this simple program (globals are normally unnecessary and frowned upon when not needed).

  - use a mutable argument (such as a dictionary) to store points
- Unnecessarily to use f-strings in all your print statements.  Unnecessary usage confuses the reader since they are looking for a variable in your string.
- software is a meaningless name for a function

  - use something more descriptive of its purpose such as update_points

**Improved Code**

```
#The error is your global statements should be inside function software since the global keyword allows us to modify variables outside of the current scope. You need it in 
# The questions and answers should be in a data structure rather than each being its own variable
#    This allows you to interate over the questions
# Most of your print statements you can use string literal rather than f-strings since they don't use a variable
#        Unnecessarily using f-strings confuses the code reviewer since they are looking for a variable in your string
#QUESTION

questions = ["TRUE OR FALSE: The lightest atom is hydrogen",
             "TRUE OR FALSE: Osmium is one of the densest atom if not the most",
             "TRUE OR FALSE: chemistry is the branch of science that deals with the identification of the substances of which matter is composed; the investigation of their properties and the ways in which they interact, combine, and change; and the use of these processes to form new substances.",
             "TRUE OR FALSE: There are 200 elements discovered in history",
             "TRUE OR FALSE: Dmitri Ivanovich Mendeleev was a Russian chemist and inventor. He is best known for formulating the Periodic Law and creating a version of the periodic table of elements.",
             "TRUE OR FALSE: The earth is the center of the earth",
             "TRUE OR FALSE: The sun the the center of the earth",
             "TRUE OR FALSE: The sun makes up most of the mass in our solar system",
             "TRUE OR FALSE: Jupiter has the most moon in the solar system",
             "TRUE OR FALSE: Mars's nick name is the red planet",
             "TRUE OR FALSE: Supernova's are the biggest explosions in the universe",
             "TRUE OR FALSE: Gamma rays bursts are the biggest explosions the universe"
             "TRUE OR FALSE: All stars turn into supernovas",
             "TRUE OR FALSE: All stars turn into blacks holes",
             "TRUE OR FALSE: All stars turn into neutron stars",
             "TRUE OR FALSE: Based on the model, Juptier is the biggest planet",
             "TRUE OR FALSE: Based on the model, earth is the samllest planet",
             "TRUE OR FALSE: Based on the model, neptune is the farthest planet to the sun",
             "TRUE OR FALSE: Based on the model, the sun is the biggest object",
             "TRUE OR FALSE: Based on the model the asteroid belt is located between Jupiter and Mars"]
 #____________________________________________________________________
 #ANSWER KEY
answers = ["True",
           "True",
           "True",
           "False",
           "True",
           "False",
           "True",
           "True",
           "False",
           "True",
           "False",
           "True",
           "False",
           "False",
           "False",
           "True",
           "False",
           "True",
           "True",
           "True"]

def update_points(points, key):
    '''
        Updates points for player1 & player2
    
    '''
    print(p1, p2, key)
    if p1!=key and p2!=key:
        print("Both of you got it wrong")
        
    elif p2==key and p1!=key:
        print(f"{p2name} got it right")
        # increment player 2 points
        points[p2name] += 100
        
    elif p1==key and p2!=key:
        
        print(f"{p1name} got it right")
        # increment player 1 points
        points[p1name] += 100
       
    elif p1==key and p2==key:
        print("both of you got it right")
        # increment both players points
        points[p1name] += 100
        points[p2name] += 100
        
    return points    # updated points


startkey = "Start"
rulekey = "Rules"

start = input('''Hello to the tester 9000
                 Type start to start
                 type rules to know how to play!''').capitalize().strip()

if start==rulekey:
    rule = input("You need aleast 2 players to play this game\n\neverytime you get the question right you get 100 points\n\n the person with the most points after 20 questions is the winner\ntype start to start")
    
rule = "Start"
    
if start==startkey or rule==startkey:
    p1name = input("what is your name player one: ")
    p2name = input("what is your name player two: ")
    
    # Initialize points for each player
    points = {}
    points[p1name] = 0
    points[p2name] = 0
    
    for i, q in enumerate(questions):
        # loop over each question in list.  Enumerate provides the index of the quesiton
        print(f"time for question {i}")
        print(questions[i])

        # Get answers
        p1 = input(f"{p1name} turn").capitalize().strip()
        p2 = input(f"{p2name} turn").capitalize().strip()

        # Update points
        points = update_points(points, answers[i])

        print(f"Player 1 points: {points[p1name]}")
        print(f"Player 2 points: {points[p2name]}")
```